# How do I input a binary number

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, palindrome

I was doing a question on checking if a binary number is palindrome or not. 
The implementation I had could check it for 4 or 5 but as soon as I entered 1001 it interpreted it as thousand and one and not 9. How to do this?

```
 unsigned int rev=0;
 unsigned int temp=x;

 while(temp!=0)
 {
     cout<<rev<<" ";
     rev=(rev<<1)|(temp%2);
     temp=temp>>1;
     cout<<endl<<temp;

 }
 cout<<rev<<" ";
 if(rev==x)
     return true;
 else
     return false;
```

Comment: How about you post what you tried

Comment: Can you show or explain what approach you are currently taking?  How are you storing your variables/parameters (what data types)?

Comment: @Ben i edited it as per your request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strtol or any other function

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    long x; 
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;
    char * pEnd;
    x = strtol(str.c_str(), &pEnd, 2);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is very good... Thanx a ton... Sorry cant upvote requires 15 reputation.. :)

Comment: @SarasArya You can accept his answer if it solves your problem